# arp add 255.255.255.255 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff (router)

Tags: router, wake-on-lan, arp, broadcast

If I add arp entry in router config like this:

```
arp add 255.255.255.255 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Open specific port:

```
port: 1009 ip: 255.255.255.255
```

Will it broadcast message to all connected devices?

I'm sending wake on lan package.

What if I add random IP like:

```
arp add 192.168.1.15 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

port: 1009 ip: 192.168.1.15
```

Will it still broadcast to all network devices?

Comment: You have a few questions on WoL here - I am still not clear why you want to broadcast.  You know the mac you are trying to wake, so why not put that in your arp table?

Comment: Simple. My router deletes ARP entries when they had been utilized and after server had been shutdown. Arp entry in form of IP FF:FF:FF sticks for some reason and I don't have to add it to arp table again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `arp add 255.255.255.255 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` cannot be done, router gives error.

`arp add 192.168.1.15 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` works fine for WOL functionality from WAN.